# How to select a Taxonomy term in a Pane's settings and send it as an argument to Views?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, panels

I have a taxonomy vocabulary *Help* with several terms, representing different topics. I also have a Panel page where I would like to add Panes that contain all nodes with a certain *Help* term. My idea was to create a content View that accepts filtering on a provided *Help* term. Next, I would simply add this View to my Panel page and select the desired *Help* term from a list in the Pane's settings.

I more or less succeeded: my View has a relation *Content: Taxonomy terms in node* (where I selected the *Help* vocabulary) and a contextual filter *Taxonomy term: name* (where I set up an appropriate validation criterium *Term name*). This works fine, but I have to manually type the term name in my Pane's settings. That is not so efficient, because the term names might change in the future.

Is it possible to pick the desired term name from a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe my initial request has a valid answer, but it is easier to forget about the contextual filter and only keep a relationship *Content: Taxonomy terms in node* to select the correct vocabulary. Next, filter on *Taxonomy Term: Term* and select the previously added relationship. Now you can select the required term from a list! Of course, you can duplicate the Views block as many times as needed and only override the taxonomy term. Finally, these blocks can be used in a Panel or elsewhere.